# Replace \n in BufferedWriter.write()?

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

I have a String that contains for example "Name: Foo \n Date: 12/13/11 \n"

When I do BufferedWriter.write(String) to a text file it actually outputs the \n is there anyway to do a replace on \n to something that when written to a text file will signify a line break?

Here is sample code.

```
String input = "Name: adfasd \n AN: asdfasdf \n";
Writer textOutput = null;
File file = new File("write.txt");  
textOutput = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
textOutput.write( input );
textOutput.close();
```

The output would be

http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7694/exampleve.png

Comment: Please show some actual code.

Comment: the output image link is broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses CR+LF line endings as opposed to LF endings. You should be able to use `\r\n` to get your desired result.

Wikipedia has an article about [newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 1):

If the string contains the text \n as opposed to the character \n, then you can do

```
String text = "Line 1 \\n Line2";
System.out.println(text);
System.out.println(text.replace("\\n", "\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, I just tested the following code, and the resulting file displays the message on two lines :

```
public void test() throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/someDir/test.txt"));
    writer.write("Hello\nWorld");
    writer.close();
}
```

Result :

```
Hello 
World
```

Comment: What .txt editor did you use? Does it open fine in notepad for you (if you are using Windows)?

Comment: GEdit on Linux (Gnome). Linux and Windows use different end-of-line sequences (\r\n on Windows, \n on linux). Try to replace the \n by \r\n and see if it corrects your problem on windows ?